# Making a post request with only checkboxes

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

I want to make a post request to the same page with only checkboxes. Much like this page ([link](http://codeforces.com/contest/447/standings/)). Notice the "show unofficial" on the right side of the table top. After it is clicked, it gives a post request to the same page. I want the same feature in my page but with two checkboxes. But it is not reloading the page, not even with one checkbox. A part of My code:

```
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="official">OFFICIAL
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="unOfficial">UNOFFICIAL
    </form>
```

Comment: Checkbox won't submit on click by default. Are you using jQuery on your project? So we can suggest an appropriated solution.

Comment: Yes, I am using jquery script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case, you will need some javascript to achieve this. You will need to set an onchange event on your checkboxes which will trigger the form's submit.

Couple of other things:

- for your HTML to be correct, your input tags need a closing slash,
- labels arround the OFFICIAL and UNOFFICIAL linked to the relevant checkbox (with the use of ids) will be more userfriendly,
- because the checkboxes are about the same kind of data (an official and unofficial statuses), their name should be the same, and their value different.

Here an example using JQuery:

```
    <form id="myform" class="form-inline" role="form" action="" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" value="official" name="some-name" id="checkbox-official" />
        <label for="checkbox-official">OFFICIAL</label>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myform input[type="checkbox"].form-control').change(function(){
            $('#myform').submit();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks padawin. It works. And no, both checkboxes can also be checked, so they are having different names.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually look at the source of the page and do the same thing.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" class="toggle-show-unofficial" style="margin-top: 0.5em;"><input type='hidden' name='csrf_token' value='5680chchb2e97fg076f5f9gf5efggbgb'/>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="toggleShowUnofficial"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="newShowUnofficialValue" value="true"/>
    <input name="showUnofficial" id="showUnofficial" type="checkbox" />
     <label for="showUnofficial" style="position: relative; bottom: 0.4em;">show unofficial</label>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".toggle-show-unofficial input[name='showUnofficial']").change(function() {
    $(".toggle-show-unofficial").submit();
});
```

You can see they have a jQuery handler for the `change` event set up to submit the form when the box is changed. Pretty simple!

Answer (score 0):

you can use onChange attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange="this.form.submit()">
```